# Solr syntax for phrase query

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a field with definition:

```
"replace-field": {
    "name":"search_words",
    "type":"lowercase",
    "stored":true,
    "indexed": true,
    "multiValued": true
}
```

that contains sentences as array (thus multiValued: true):

```
"id":500
"search_words":["How much oil should you pour into the engine",
          "How important is engine oil?]
```

How should I create a query thatwould return that document (with id = 500) when user inputs phrase "engine oil"?
With single term queries I can user `*engine*` and it would find that document becasue `engine` is in the middle of the sentence but I can't find a way to be able to seearch for phrases in sentences. Is it even possible using solr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solr supports phrase search, and is what it was actually designed for. Wildcard searches are not really the way you should use Solr by default - the field type should tell Solr how to process the text in the field to make you get hits when querying it in a regular way.

In this case the standard `text_en` would probably work fine, or a field definition with a Standard Tokenizer and a lowercasefilter (and possibly a WordDelimiterGraphFilter to get rid of special characters).

The query would then be `search_words:"engine oil"`.